# How to ssh into system connected to same network switch?

Tags: linux, ssh, ethernet, switch, remote

I have a few systems which are connected to the same network switch. All of them are running linux / Ubuntu 18.

I want to remotely access one machine to another through ssh.

That is, if I'm operating on one of the machines, I want to remotely access the other through ssh.

How can I go about it?

**Assume I do not know the ip addresses of any of the machines and just have access to one of them. I would need the steps to obtain the ip addresses of the other machine. I'm ONLY allowed to operate a single machine on the same switch which I have access to**

Eg. I have Machine A, B, C, D connected to switch S. I can only have access to A and nothing else.

I came across some SO answers which advised the use of arp -a but never went beyond that.

What steps would I have to take to do the above?

Answer (score 1):

Use `arp -a` and try every address listed under your main network subnet. Of course the machines have to have a configured ssh access and you have to know the configured port numbers it could be anything not just 22.

Also a switch is not equal to a router, you have to [manually](https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=133072) configure the network on each of them without a DHCP router.